# Code-Based migration not working on Oracle database if username or schema name changed

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I want to apply Code-Based Migration if any new Oracle Database connect with application (`Windows form application - Entity Framework 6 - C#`).

Currently i have generated Migration with specific database and schema i.e. (`Database = 'TestDB' | Schema = 'PDBADMIN'`). But, in my case schema name will be different each new connection with this application. In short not any schema/username fix for connect new Oracle Database with this application. So, when user want to run application(exe) then Code-Based migration will auto execute but it will throw exception if connected Oracle Database does not have same username or schema name (same as during migration generation time available with specific database).

**What i tried from my side.**

Through application debug mode i applied same migration with another Oracle database where Schema/Username different i.e.(`Schema ='PDBTEST' | Database = 'NewDB'`) but it throw exception.

> Unable to update database to match the current model because there are
> pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the
> pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic
> migration.

**Working Scenario**

If i connect my application exe with same schema/username in Oracle then it's works.

**Not working Scenario**

But not work with another schema/username with new database connection (Database is empty) .

How to resolve this issue ?

[image]
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!